# In Gulp(4) : Why do you not need an onChange event handler for invoking a stream, but only for reload?

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

My gulpfile 4 works fine. But I am just slightly curious why I need no on('change'....) when invoking a method calling a browserSync.stream()

Below is my Gulp4 gulpfile and it works fine

But I am curious as to why, in the watch method below, my sass watch does not require an onchange handler.

If I where to remove the change handler from the watch of my script and html files and try to call reload directly, then those two will no longer work.

Yet, the sass watch requires none. Hmm. Why.

Here is the code

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");
const postcss = require("gulp-postcss");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
const browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

const paths = {
  styles: {
    src: "src/scss/*.scss",
    dest: "src/css"
  },

  scripts: {
    src: "src/js/*.js"
  },

  watched: {
    src: "src/*.html"
  }
};

function style() {
  return gulp
    .src(paths.styles.src)
    //Sourcemaps first so we get mapping once the compilation is done
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .on("error", sass.logError)
    //Sass one now run auto prefix
    .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer]))
    //Write the sourcemap
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

//Parallell to this, we need a watch task for the Scss
function watch() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./src"
    }
  });

  //Watch JavaScript files; just calling reload directly at the moment as we're not babeling
  gulp.watch(paths.scripts.src).on('change', reload);
  //Watch Sass files
  gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, style)
  //Lets make the html our trigger for reload as set in paths object above
  gulp.watch(paths.watched.src).on('change', reload);
}

function reload() {
  browserSync.reload();
}

//Expose to npm
exports.watch = watch;
exports.style = style;

// Default task invoked by typing 'gulp' in npm
gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel(style, watch))
```

Thanks in advance, I owe you a glass of Madeira.
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can call `reload` directly, but gulp needs a way of knowing when the task is finished. Adding a callback should do the trick:

```js
function reload(cb) {
  browserSync.reload();
  cb();
}
```

Comment: Yes; I think I must have been overtired when asking this question. I think I should have replaced my late day coffee with a cup of refreshing mint tea. Thanks.